# Loading 'Image Service Package' crashes Management Studio

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, sql-server-2008, ssms

I'm getting the following error on my SQL Server when I log into the system:

[image]

I ran a repair on SSMS successfully, but it did not resolve the issue.

The following error message is recorded in Event Viewer:

> Faulting application name: Ssms.exe, version: 2017.140.17289.0, time stamp: 0x5befcf0a
>   
> Faulting module name: KERNELBASE.dll, version: 10.0.17763.348, time stamp: 0x53015794
>   
> Exception code: 0xe0434352
>   
> Fault offset: 0x0011c632
>   
> Faulting process id: 0x4b78
>   
> Faulting application start time: 0x01d4ea2b07126bd9
>   
> Faulting application path: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL 
>   
> Server\140\Tools\Binn\ManagementStudio\Ssms.exe
>   
> Faulting module path: C:\WINDOWS\System32\KERNELBASE.dll
>   
> Report Id: 7ad5c801-9ad5-42e0-9f32-933c4f3eb0c6
>   
> Faulting package full name: 
>   
> Faulting package-relative application ID:

Comment: Try uninstalling 17.9.1 completely and either reinstalling from scratch or [trying 18.0 RC1 instead](https://cloudblogs.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2019/03/28/sql-server-management-studio-18-0-release-candidate-1-is-now-available/).

Comment: @AaronBertrand , Its still the same error

Comment: So what's in the activity log file that the error message tells you to look at?

Comment: ERROR SetSite failed for package [Image Service Package]
ERROR End package load [Image Service Package]

Comment: How many different versions of Visual Studio do you have installed? This seems like a configuration issue, SSMS just happens to be the symptom. I suggest opening a case with Microsoft support if threads like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31918711/61305) don't help.